# Program crashes when trying to convert const char* to long long

Tags: c++

When the program runs, it crashes at long long thisLong = atoll(c); Is there any reason for this?

```
string ConvertToBaseTen(long long base4) {
    stringstream s;
    s << base4;
    string tempBase4;
    s >> tempBase4;
    s.clear();
    string tempBase10;
    long long total = 0;
    for (signed int x = 0; x < tempBase4.length(); x++) {
         const char* c = (const char*)tempBase4[x];
         long long thisLong = atoll(c);
         total += (pow(thisLong, x));
    }
    s << total;
    s >> tempBase10;
    return tempBase10;
}
```

Comment: Proper indentation would be great

Comment: `tempBase4[x]` returns `char` not `const char *`

Comment: `atoll` has no error checking, and why would you go out of your way to use it on a `char`?

Comment: note that in order to clear the contents of your stringstream variable `s` you do not write `s.clear()` you should write `s.str("")`. *clear()* just clears error bits.

Comment: Im converting bases, so I need to isolate each digit of the number

Answer (score 3):

[atoll](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) needs `const char*` as input, but `tempBase4[x]` only returns `char`.

If you want to convert each character in string to decimal, try:

```
for (signed int x = 0; x < tempBase4.length(); x++) {
   int value = tempBase4[i] -'0';
   total += (pow(value , x));
}
```

Or if you want to convert the whole tempBase to `long long`:

```
long long thisLong = atoll(tempBase4.c_str());
total += (pow(thisLong, x));
```